# Specifying points in a question as m + n in exam class

Tags: exam

See the following example. In the first question, points in assigned in the parts are specified separately, 6 in the first one, 4 in the second one.

However, for some local requirements, I need this to specify as 6 + 4, which I try in the second question.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Placement of marks 
\bracketedpoints 
\pointsinrightmargin
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{20.0mm}
\extrawidth{-15.0mm}



\begin{document}

% Total points is wrongly reported as 16
Total points: \numpoints

\begin{questions}
  \question 
  \begin{parts}
    \part [6] \lipsum[1]
    \part [4] \lipsum[2]
  \end{parts}

  % The following produces a spurious + 4+ 4+ 4 in the output just
  % before this question

  \question [6 + 4] 
  \begin{parts}
    \part \lipsum[1]
    \part \lipsum[2]
  \end{parts}


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

However, the above produces two undesired effects.

1. The  reported total points in incorrect.
2. Some spurious text  appears  before the question in the output.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the command for adding points to the counter so that it accepts an expression:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Placement of marks 
\bracketedpoints 
\pointsinrightmargin
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{20.0mm}
\extrawidth{-15.0mm}

\makeatletter
%% patch the command for adding points
%% so that it accepts an expression
\patchcmd{\addto@hlfcntr}{0#2}{\numexpr0#2\relax}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% Total points is wrongly reported as 16
Total points: \numpoints

\begin{questions}
  \question 
  \begin{parts}
    \part [6] \lipsum[1]
    \part [4] \lipsum[2]
  \end{parts}

  % The following produces a spurious + 4+ 4+ 4 in the output just
  % before this question

  \question [6 + 4] 
  \begin{parts}
    \part \lipsum[1]
    \part \lipsum[2]
  \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is twisted work around:

```
% The following produces a spurious + 4+ 4+ 4 in the output just
      % before this question
       \noaddpoints    %% don't add points
       \question [6 + 4]
       \addpoints       %% add them now onwards
       \pointformat{}   %% don't display points
      \begin{parts}
        \part[6] \lipsum[1]
        \part[4] \lipsum[2]
      \end{parts}
      \bracketedpoints  %% start displaying points
```

Looks bit hacky but works.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Placement of marks
\bracketedpoints
\pointsinrightmargin
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{20.0mm}
\extrawidth{-15.0mm}



    \begin{document}

    % Total points is wrongly reported as 16
    Total points: \numpoints

    \begin{questions}
      \question
      \begin{parts}
        \part [6] \lipsum[1]
        \part [4] \lipsum[2]
      \end{parts}

      % The following produces a spurious + 4+ 4+ 4 in the output just
      % before this question
       \noaddpoints    %% don't add points
       \question [6 + 4]
       \addpoints       %% add them now onwards
       \pointformat{}   %% don't display points
      \begin{parts}
        \part[6] \lipsum[1]
        \part[4] \lipsum[2]
      \end{parts}
      \bracketedpoints  %% start displaying points

      \question [6]
       \addpoints
       \pointformat{}
      \begin{parts}
        \part[6] \lipsum[1]
        \part[4] \lipsum[2]
      \end{parts}


    \end{questions}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple but elegant. With some macros, this can be automated some more. But I will want to wait a bit before I accept this answer (as I always to do).